# How to add file attachment to existing contact form?

Tags: php, html, forms

I've been trying to customize a contact form that came with HTML site template to add file attachment / upload but with no success. Reason for trying to do this instead of embedding different contact form is simply because it's responsive and consistent with the rest of the site template. Any help would be great.

This is the HTML part of the contact form:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="span9">

        <form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="#">
            <p class="contact-name">
                <input id="contact_name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" value="" name="name" />
            </p>
            <p class="contact-email">
                <input id="contact_email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" value="" name="email" />
            </p>
            <p class="contact-message">
                <textarea id="contact_message" placeholder="Your Message" name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p class="contact-submit">
                <a id="contact-submit" class="submit" href="#">Send Your Email</a>
            </p>

            <div id="response">

            </div>
        </form>
```

and here's the PHP part:

```
<?php

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

$admin_email = 'your@yourdomain.com'; // Your Email
$message_min_length = 5; // Min Message Length


class Contact_Form{
function __construct($details, $email_admin, $message_min_length){

    $this->name = stripslashes($details['name']);
    $this->email = trim($details['email']);
    $this->subject = 'Contact from Your Website'; // Subject 
    $this->message = stripslashes($details['message']);

    $this->email_admin = $email_admin;
    $this->message_min_length = $message_min_length;

    $this->response_status = 1;
    $this->response_html = '';
}


private function validateEmail(){
    $regex = '/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i';

    if($this->email == '') { 
        return false;
    } else {
        $string = preg_replace($regex, '', $this->email);
    }

    return empty($string) ? true : false;
}


private function validateFields(){
    // Check name
    if(!$this->name)
    {
        $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter your name</p>';
        $this->response_status = 0;
    }

    // Check email
    if(!$this->email)
    {
        $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter an e-mail address</p>';
        $this->response_status = 0;
    }

    // Check valid email
    if($this->email && !$this->validateEmail())
    {
        $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter a valid e-mail address</p>';
        $this->response_status = 0;
    }

    // Check message length
    if(!$this->message || strlen($this->message) < $this->message_min_length)
    {
        $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter your message. It should have at least '.$this->message_min_length.' characters</p>';
        $this->response_status = 0;
    }
}


private function sendEmail(){
    $mail = mail($this->email_admin, $this->subject, $this->message,
         "From: ".$this->name." <".$this->email.">\r\n"
        ."Reply-To: ".$this->email."\r\n"
    ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

    if($mail)
    {
        $this->response_status = 1;
        $this->response_html = '<p>Thank You!</p>';
    }
}


function sendRequest(){
    $this->validateFields();
    if($this->response_status)
    {
        $this->sendEmail();
    }

    $response = array();
    $response['status'] = $this->response_status;   
    $response['html'] = $this->response_html;

    echo json_encode($response);
}
 }


 $contact_form = new Contact_Form($_POST, $admin_email, $message_min_length);
 $contact_form->sendRequest();

 ?>
```

I've tried many different forms but with all I have to heavily change form's CSS/HTML formatting which results in site template breaking along the way.

Comment: Easiest way, use PHPmailer.

Answer (score 0):

read this page http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php

add `<input type="file" >` to html And Read top Link for attach file in php mail

download php simple mail script on Github
https://github.com/eoghanobrien/php-simple-mail

Comment: I can't get it to work. Email without attachment works just fine, but i can't get it to send the actual attachment. Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: Download `https://github.com/eoghanobrien/php-simple-mail` And get easy Attachment

Comment: It's Workable .Please Accept My Answer... ;)

Comment: I'm telling you I can't get it to work with my current form, can you explain it a bit more elaborate please? :)

Comment: Your programming information Is Very Low.`simple mail` is very easy to use... :(

Comment: I know, that's why I'm asking for help. Thank you anyway.